# Where and what kind of JSP file to place in the below shown image. and what is the use of .tag file in hybris

Tags: jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

In "**hybris**", which folder should **JSP page** be placed or created in **yacceleratorstorefront**?

[image: WEB-INF sub-folders]

Answer (score 0):

You have to place it in `pages` folder because the `VIEW-RESOLVER` property is set to look in the `pages` folder.
The `tag` file is a template which can be used in multiple pages. For example you have the same footer, it would be to hard modify it every time in each page, instead, you can create a tag called `footer.tag` maybe, and include it in your `jsp` pages.